# Magento display something custom on account create page

Tags: php, magento

I want to display a line at this url of magento:

index.php/customer/account/create/

I tried to put event in config.xml, in my module...
(I am using custom local module to customize my magento)

```
<controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_create>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_modulename_controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_create_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>onCustomerAccountCreateBefore</method>
                    </namespace_modulename_controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_create_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_create>
```

And when I echo in the function, in observer.php,

```
public function onCustomerAccountCreateBefore (Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        Mage::log('function triggered',null,'logs.log');
        echo 'test';
    }
```

It successfully logs everything, and it prints test on the screen, but the problem is, it prints test on the top of screen, I don't want it to print test on top of screen but somewhere in the middle like before the register form, above the register form or below it, but not on top of screen...

Comment: Are you wanting to customise this area or simply display a new block for all potential customers?

Comment: simply display one single line which says "hello world" or something similar, hmm new block i guess

Comment: Yep, just add a new block into your local.xml - you don't need an observer at all.

Comment: the reason I need observer is because I am using a custom event, so i need the observer

Comment: What custom event?  You want to display a block, on a page, correct?